# Style all child elements of a disabled or readonly element with CSS (SASS)

Tags: html, css, sass

It would be nice if you could tell me how to style all children of a disabled or readonly DOM-Element.

My HTML-code looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper" disabled="disabled">
    <label>
            Test
            <input type="text">
    </label>
</div>
```

and my SCSS-code like this:

```
.wrapper:disabled{
    *{
         background-color: grey;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't matter whether the .wrapper element is disabled or not, the star-style of .wrapper is dominant.

Is there a way to suppress this style until the parent div is not disabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.wrapper[disabled] * {
         background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" disabled="disabled">
    <label>
            Test
            <input type="text">
    </label>
</div>
```

The css selector should be .wrapper[disabled]